# Regex matching only set of items

Tags: java, regex

The allowed input should only consist of these words {ENTER, PLUS, MINUS} and non-negative numbers.

An example:
ENTER34 it should be false and if I write a number or the correct word it should be evaluated as true.

```
ENTER -> true
PLUS -> true
MINUS -> true
any nonnegative number -> true

TEST -> false
-45 -> false
BLABLA -> false
```

How do I implement this as a regular expression in java? I have tried the following with no result. (I'm not an expert on regex..)

```
myString.matches("{[0-9]}{ENTER|PLUS|MINUS}")
```

**The user is only allowed to either input a number or the correct word.**

Comment: Looks like you should start with a regex manual or tutorial. Your attempt is *way* off. Should the number come before or after the word?

Comment: The user is only allowed to either input a number or the correct word.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Can you include some valid and invalid matches in question.

Comment: There's no need for tags in your title. If you want to include it, try to work it in naturally. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
(\d+|ENTER|PLUS|MINUS)
```

I.e. one of:

- `\d+`, i.e. one ore more digits.
- Literally `ENTER`.
- Literally `PLUS`.
- Literally `MINUS`.

You make a few mistakes in your attempt. One of them is your use of `{}`. Another is the lack of `()` when using `|`. If you want to get better at regex a tutorial might be a good start, or at the very least read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes I will read the documentation for better understanding as this was needed urgently.

Comment: If you ask me; the more urgent it is the more need to read the documentation. Have fun learning regex, once you master it it's a great tool.